# Код на GoLang - Sever который принимает Req и возвращает его в UrlDecode

Tags: golang, сервер

Не могу написать код на golang.
В main.go необходимо следующее

- Запустить сервер который слушает запросы на порту 9501
- Получить полный запрос и декодировать его ( Кириллица ).
  Запрос делаю на сайте вида [https://site.ru/вАсЯ/КоЛя?x=Петя&y=ДиМа](https://site.ru/%D0%B2%D0%90%D1%81%D0%AF/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%9B%D1%8F?x=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F&y=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%9C%D0%B0)
- Вывести на страницы полную декодированную строку.
  PS "3 часа в пустоту"

Вот мой код:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url" )

func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    u, err := url.Parse(r.URL.Path)
    if err != nil {
        uri:= u.String() return uri
    }
}

func main() {
    uri:= http.HandleFunc("/", handleRequest)
    fmt.Fprint(url)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9501", nil)
}
```

Comment: Ну файл начинается со строк `package main`... хотя стоп! а где ваш код, попытки решения? Учитывая что это 3 строки кода (не учитывая обвязку), то вам стоит пойти Учится) но **за деньги да**.. специально для таких как Вы

Comment: Ну вот код: package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "net/http"
 "net/url"
)

func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    u, err := url.Parse(r.URL.Path)
 if err != nil{
  uri:= u.String()
  return uri 
 }
}

func main() {
 uri:= http.HandleFunc("/", handleRequest)
 fmt.Fprint(url) 
 http.ListenAndServe(":9501", nil)
}

Comment: рекомендую пояснения, код и прочее писать в вопросе) читать ваш код без форматирования в комментах - себя не уважать) так же рекомендую ознакомится с правилами сообщества и его стандартами) в противном случае вы будете долго и нудно что-то у кого-то спрашивать.

Comment: Вот посмотрите: https://gobyexample.com.ru/http-servers

Comment: Вставил код в вопрос.